# How to manually configure Nameserver without breaking Ubuntuone?

Tags: ubuntu-one, network-manager

If I allow the network manager to "manage" my nameserver, it resolves to the IP address of the router. This effectively makes both Evolution and Opera unuseable, slowing them both to a crawl (I am sure other things are affected, but I have yet to notice).

However, if I manually configure resolv.conf with the ACTUAL nameservers pulled from my router, and make it immutable with the "chattr -i" command, both Evolution and Opera run as they should, but this breaks Ubuntu One. I get the dreaded list of "unknown" everythings...

Any idea how to make both function properly?

Answer (score 2):

What you should do is to configure your system to override the default nameserver (given by DHCP), in a way that it is compatible with NetworkManager.
And the way to do this is to add your selected nameservers in the dhcp client configuration file, at `/etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf`.

One way to do this is to uncomment the `prepend domain-name-servers` line.
Make it look something like

```
prepend domain-name-servers 1.2.3.4 1.2.3.5;
```

If you are really interested in speedy DNS lookups, you can cache the DNS requests using, for example, `dnsmasq`. Ask a new question for this, use as title `How can I speed up the DNS requests with caching`.